# Infinite Scroll with AngularFire and Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll based list using Ionic and Firebase. The list must be sorted in descending order. I'm currently using orderByKey and limitToLast to achieve. Unfortunately this means that I'm missing out on the realtime updates that FirebaseArray provides. I'd like to underdstand how I can implement infinite scroll with descending order based on key with FirebaseArray. I've already tried using the FirebaseUtil library (https://gist.github.com/katowulf/7adb5775dce44cbbba0a) but cannot seem to implement descending order. Can you please help?

Thanks,
Akshay